# iPhone Testing Microphone Using Emulator

Tags: iphone

Can I test the voice recording using the iPhone emulator or do I need the actual device?

Comment: Not yet! I was hoping to get an answer so that will save me the trouble!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - If you have a microphone on your Mac then the emulator will get the audio from the microphone. iMacs and MacBooks have one built in - for other models you may have to plug in an external microphone.

Answer (score 1):

Note that might be good for a rough test but the volume in could vary substantially from your computer, so you REALLY want to test at least once on an actual device before you ship.

Comment: Oh of course! I would never ship anything by just testing it on the emulator alone! Thanks for the advice though!